# React ошибка Attempted import error: 'DataUtils' is not exported from 'three'

Tags: javascript, reactjs, 3d, three.js, webgl

Использую в своём React приложении

1. [Three.js](https://threejs.org/),
2. [react-three-fiber](https://github.com/pmndrs/react-three-fiber)
3. и [react-three/drei](https://github.com/pmndrs/drei).

Когда я пытаюсь импортировать **OrbitControls** из **react-three/drei**, получаю ошибку:

```
Attempted import error: 'DataUtils' is not exported from 'three'.
```

*Мои зависимости:

Three.js - 0.122.0,

react-three-fiber - 7.0.0,

react-three/drei - 7.3.1*

Использую старую версию **Three.js** так как в дальнейшем в проекте нужен **Freesurfer**, а он совместим с этой версией.

Пытался использовать прошлые версией **fiber**(*5.1.4*) и **drei**(*2.0.1*), по датам соответствующие **Three.js**, но получаю ошибку:

```
Module not found: Can't resolve 'react-three-fiber' in
'D:\work\bb\client\node_modules\@react-three\drei'
```

С последней версией Three.js всё работает.

Мой код:

```
import React from "react";
import "./viewer.css";
import { Canvas } from "@react-three/fiber";
import { OrbitControls } from "@react-three/drei";

export default function Viewer() {

  return (
    <div className="canvasDiv">
      <Canvas className="webgl">
        <ambientLight intensity={0.1} />
        <directionalLight color="red" position={[0, 0, 5]} />
        <mesh>
          <boxGeometry args={[2, 2, 2]} />
          <meshStandardMaterial />
        </mesh>
      </Canvas>
    </div>
  );
}
```